# How to conclude from a target IP to associated URL(s)?

Tags: webserver, ip, web-service, url, reconnaissance

Given a target IP or target IP(s). Is there any reasonable way to conclude from the IP to hosted URL(s).

I can scan the IP(s) with `nmap` and possibly conclude on which ports a webserver is running, but not which URL(s) may be served there.

I could also simply access the IP in the browser with the identified ports and see if there's are default redirect in place.

**Is there a reasonable way to conclude from IP to hosted URL(s)?**

*edit:* I'm not talking about directories of one hosted URL (e.g. `example.com/uploads`, `example.com/images`, ...).
I'm talking about the scenario, when multiple different URLs are hosted via one IP address (e.g. IP `127.0.0.1` hosts `example.com` and `somethingelse.com`).

I do know about reverse DNS searches, but are there any other techniques?

Comment: Is it private IP or a public IP? Have you tried interrogating the DNS records? A simple nslookup or whois search should do the trick. You may need set them to do a reverse lookup but most tools will do that for you automatically.

Comment: Try a reverse DNS lookup?  You can use something like http://mxtoolbox.com/ReverseLookup.aspx

Comment: Reverse DNS lookup is the only thing I'm aware of - I was wondering if there are other techniques. Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 2):

Crawlers can find these over different ways:

1. Read sitemap files or the robot.txt
2. Use statuscodes like 403 or 404 to guess whether there is a file or not

Comment: This would help find directories of one hosted URL (e.g. `example.com/uploads`, example.com/images`), rather then different URLs (e.g. IP `127.0.0.1` hosts `example.com` and `somethingelse.com`). I might have not been clear enough in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Good idea to put the address in a browser window, using the open ports revealed by nmap.
Even better, use PuTTY and set it up as a telnet client to explore those ports.

But that won't  necessarily tell you much.

Try mine and you will see:  The address is 50.87.249.67, and the site http://www.calttc.net/default.html is on the shared server.

Knowing just the IP address will definitely not lead you to my root site at http://calttc.net nor to the subsites which do not start with www.  It also will not point you to my proof-of-concept where I try out PHP for the first time, at:  http://www.calttc.net/login.htm  (Nothing is saved if you try this out - it just echoes the username field back)

Here are several research tools that might help figure out what an IP adddress points towards:

http://itools.com/tool/arin-whois-domain-search

https://www.ultratools.com/tools/ipWhoisLookup

https://mxtoolbox.com/ReverseLookup.aspx

---- EDIT:  @Schroeder found another one that went the furthest towards finding my hosting service:  http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/50.87.249.67
Kudos for that one.

Comment: I think you meant to talk about DNS searches, not whois

Comment: If I search your IP, it doesn't come up with your domain name or any other domain name: https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-50-87-0-0-1/pft?s=50.87.249.67

Comment: A reverse lookup only gets you so far: https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=ptr%3a50.87.249.67&run=toolpage

Comment: You need to do a DNS search: http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/50.87.249.67 (Domain neighbours section)

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  In the DNS there may or may not be a PTR record.  My VPN does not so you wouldn't even be able to tell which state I am in if I gave it to you.